# typescript security hotspot in environement.ts file, SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I have an environement.ts file like this:

```
export const environment = {
      production: false,
      HOST: 'http://192.192.192.1:8081/Services/api',
      API_ENDPOINT: '',
      API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN: '',
      ASSETS_PATH: 'assets/images/',
      ENV:'dev'
    };
    environment.API_ENDPOINT = environment.HOST + '/web/';
    environment.API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN = environment.HOST + '/login/userlogin/';
```

SonarQube is givng Security Hotspot on this line:  `HOST: 'http://192.192.192.1:8081/Services/api'`, I am not sure what the problem/solution is. Need some help.

Thanks

Comment: Security hot-spot analysis seems not too smart or context aware, even now. Issue is [Using hardcoded IP addresses is security-sensitive](https://rules.sonarsource.com/typescript/type/Security%20Hotspot/RSPEC-1313). It expects you to review and decide it's an issue. Does not care if HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the output of SonarQube, I can't say for sure but I'm fairly confident that the issue is that you're using an http endpoint and not an https endpoint meaning that the connection would not be secured (encrypted with TLS)

Comment: ok, thanks for the clue, i will try that.